# Device Driver created with Xcode won't load

Tags: xcode4, device-driver, iokit, kernel-extension

I have implemented a Device Driver Application based on this link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html

If I try to load Device on Terminal($ sudo cp -R MyDriver.kext /tmp) I get the error:

```
No kernel file specified; using running kernel for linking.
MyDriver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.
MyDriver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.
MyDriver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.
MyDriver.kext has problems:
Validation Failures: 
    Info dictionary property value is of illegal type: 
        IOKitPersonalities->MyDriver->IOKitDebug

Authentication Failures:             File owner/permissions are incorrect (must be root:wheel, nonwritable by group/other): 
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS/MyDriver
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/Resources
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/en.lproj
        /Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings        
Warnings: 
    Personality has no CFBundleIdentifier; the kext's identifier will be inserted when sending to the IOCatalogue: 
        MyDriver
```

My Doubts are:

1. What is No Kernel file specified Error (what have I missed on my application)?
2. What is MyDriver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies?
3. My Bundle Identifier is:

   ```
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.MyCompany.driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:maanu}</string>
   ```

   what is Info dictionary property value is of illegal type:

   IOKitPersonalities->MyDriver->IOKitDebug?

   (MyDriver My application Name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** kernel dependencies.
This is specified in the **info.plist** of your driver.
Here the path to info.plist seems to be        **/Users/Rasheed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDriver-gdmnlqdybpdwzyanoeludcalqwba/Build/Products/Debug/MyDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist**

The following is the kernel dependencies of AppleHIDKeyboard.kext in the info.plist
(key)OSBundleLibraries<(/key)
(dict)
(key)com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(/key)
(string)1.4(/string)
(key)com.apple.kpi.iokit(/key)
(string)10.0.0d2(/string)
**(key)com.apple.kpi.libkern(/key)**
**(string)10.0.0d2(/string)**

(/dict)

**Second** Authentication Failures:
U can solve this issue by the following procedure to deployment your driver.
1.place **MyDriver.kext** in your Desktop.
2.open the **Terminal** app and type commands list below.
3.*sudo chown -R root:wheel ~/Desktop/MyDriver.kext*
4.*sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Desktop/MyDriver.kext*
5.*mv -f ~/Desktop/MyDriver.kext /System/Library/Extensions/*
6.*touch /System/Library/Extenstions/*

**Third** CFBundleIdentifier warning.
I am not sure what type of issue here, this warning may make your driver unexecutable.
However, u should check your driver's **info.plist**, confirm whether your driver has the **CFBundleIdentifier** key and the associate value.
Besides, u should also check the driver's project settings.

Hope this is helpful to u, have a good day!

Comment: if you don't  mind could i ask one Doubts. My USB is HID Device. As per You note i did every thing. IF i checked  on  terminal       Newtok:Desktop Rasheed$ kextutil -n -t  SampleKextDriver.kext
No kernel file specified; using running kernel for linking.
SampleKextDriver.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries). I got this Error. <key>OSBundleLibraries</key><dict>key>com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily</key><string>1.4</string><key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key><string>10.7</string><key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key><string>10.7</string></dict> What wrong did